# Exclude files form webpack in nuxt

Tags: vue.js, webpack, nuxt.js

I've added some file to my nuxt project. The files are stored in the `./content` directory. Now we got some warnings like the following one:

```
WARN  in ./content/config.yml

Module parse failed: Unexpected token (9:9)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
```

To prevent the error I've tries to exclude the file in the `nuxt.config.js`. I've added the following lines but the warning aren't gone.

```
build: {
  /*
  ** You can extend webpack config here
  */
  extend (config, ctx) {
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.yml$/,
      exclude: [
        path.resolve(__dirname, '/content/config.yml')
      ]
    }
  )
  }
}
```

Are there other options to prevent the warnings?

Comment: same problem, any luck?

Comment: I want to prevent webpack from bundling some .json files which lie in a random folder `/random-folder` into my app.js.
I don't know why webpack is even bundling them in the first place. I don't even import them into my app...

@David did you ever find a solution?